# mysqld crashed "UTC - mysqld got signal 11 "

Tags: mysql

on my CentOS release 5.10 (Final), kernel version: Linux 2.6.18-371.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 12 20:08:05 EDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux, I have mysql version mysql-5.6.17-4.el5.
My mysqld crashes after " service mysqld start " with errors in log. Could you please help:

```
2014-04-24 07:46:00 24175 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-04-24 07:46:00 24175 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-04-24 07:46:00 24175 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-04-24 07:46:00 24175 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
14:46:00 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 229484 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0xa22d290
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = ffffffffbfaeb048 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0x856f7d3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x43e)[0x828b29e]
[0xad7420]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z9get_fieldP11st_mem_rootP5Field+0x67)[0x83c3127]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x82b4db8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10acl_reloadP3THD+0x4ba)[0x82b6d7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z8acl_initb+0x134)[0x82bb984]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x938)[0x8194548]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(main+0x32)[0x8187372]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0x688ebc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(__gxx_personality_v0+0x3b9)[0x8187281]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

free command output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1034656     634984     399672          0      55416     283292
-/+ buffers/cache:     296276     738380
Swap:      2096472        144    2096328
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This should be on serverfault, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

fix described here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70431

"start the server by adding skip-grant-tables to my.cnf and check what the structure of `mysql`.`user` table looks like."

Comment: worked, saved me a day

Answer (score 1):

"As a general rule, to upgrade from one release series to another, go to the
next series rather than skipping a series. To upgrade from a release series
previous to MySQL 5.5, upgrade to each successive release series in turn
until you have reached MySQL 5.5, and then proceed with the upgrade to MySQL
5.6.".